# How to edit a child value when under a firebase auto generated key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to edit the value of "shopB" in my database. I am doing so inside of a view holder, by use of a dialog box with an edit text field and an approve button. When a user clicks on a specific transaction, they're given a dialog box where they enter the value for shopB and then click Approve.

I am struggling to do this as I cannot access that value because of the uniquely generated key that firebase has. I have many posts with similar problems to mine but as I am doing this inside of a view holder I do not see how I can use DataSnapshot. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am getting very lost.

Database Structure:
[image]

```
viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(android.view.View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                            Toast.makeText(Request.this, "Receiving: " + shopA, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ThisDialog = new Dialog(Request.this);
                            ThisDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_template);
                            final EditText Write = (EditText) ThisDialog.findViewById((R.id.write));
                            Button Approve = (Button) ThisDialog.findViewById(R.id.approve);

                            Write.setEnabled(true);
                            Approve.setEnabled(true);

                            Approve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    String newShopB = Write.getText().toString().replace(".", " ");
                                    transaction.child("key").child("shopB").setValue(newShopB);
                                    Toast.makeText(Request.this, "CustB Approval", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    ThisDialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                            ThisDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
```

This would be my code but obviously where I have "transaction.child("key")" does not find the key.

Oh and transaction is defined earlier in my code as

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
start = database.getReference("Transaction");
transaction = start.child(passedEmail);
```

Comment: I think that might want to rethink your database structure. If you don't know the key, you simply won't be able to retrieve the values. For what I guess `cloe@ test` may have multiple transactions, if you want to keep the auto generated id's maybe after you set the value, you could get the key and store it in another "pending" node, so you can have access to the id's of all your "pending" transactions. Just an idea out of guessing for lack of context of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you @Racu, I used your idea to solve my issue. As a quick work around I stored the unique key with the rest of the transaction data on transaction creation. I figure this wouldn't be an ideal solution as I would imagine there would be security issues regarding this. But this does not bother me for now as it is just for a college project which I am out of time on so for now I am happy with this as a solution and it makes my key very easily accessible for me when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution to workaround on your project:

```
start.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child(key).getChildren()) {

                //insert additional codes here
              }
            }
          });
```

Comment: I don't understand your solution. I believe I understand what it does but I don't see how this solves my problem, or helps. My problem is referencing that "key" I don't know how to access/reference it. And therefore I don't know how to set the value of "shopB" in my database.